# sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop, Error: unable to locate package

Tags: apt

When I try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` I get the error message: `unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop`. Where do I obtain the package? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

The most likely situation is that you need to update your sources for some reason,  with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It's also possible that your sources aren't set up correctly.  You can configure them in the update manager.  They are located in the file /etc/apt/sources.list - if you continue to have problems paste the source of that file here.

Comment: how do I navigate to that file? Whenever I try typing /etc/apt/...I get the message - command not found. I'm a very new beginner btw.

Comment: gedit /etc/apt/
sources.list ;if you use ubuntu gedit installed by default

Answer (score 9):

Enter the following in the terminal:

```
    sudo su
    apt-get clean
    cd /var/lib/apt
    mv lists lists.old
    mkdir -p lists/partial
    apt-get clean
    apt-get update
```